# Google Map. How to add coordinates to link from array with coordinates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-maps

I have a customized map on my page, and I need to have a possibility to redirect to the Google Maps with the way from my geo point to the corresponding point on my map, all coordinates set in the array

My link in html

```
<div id="store-2" class="popup">
 <ul class="tabs">
  <li>link to tab</li>
  <li>link to tab</li>
  <li>link to tab</li>
 </ul>
 <div id="tab1">
  <div class="btn">
   <a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr" class="location">CTA</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="tab2">
  <div class="btn">
   <a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr" class="location">CTA</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="tab3">
  <div class="btn">
   <a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr" class="location">CTA</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

My array

```
var points = [

  ["random-street-name", 48.8690284, 2.3215802, "store-1"],

  ["random-street-name", 48.8654515, 2.3010255, "store-2"],

  ["random-street-name", 48.8159057, 2.3060255, "store-3"],

  ["random-street-name", 38.8698015, 2.3078555, "store-4"],

  ["random-street-name", 48.8912657, 2.3875255, "store-5"],

];
```

Script that should do this

```
storeLocator.moveToStore = function (){
var $pos = $storeInfoItems; // wrapper for block
var $navigateLink = $pos.find('.location'); //link that should be replaced
var geolocationAccepted = false;

  var success = function(pos) {
    for (var i=0; i<points.length; i++) {

      var posLatitude = points[i][1]; //coordinates for array
      var posLongitude = points[i][2]; //coordinates for array
      var crd = pos.coords;
      var curLatitude = crd.latitude;
      var curLongitude = crd.longitude;
      var navigateUrl = String($navigateLink.attr('href'));
      var saddr = 'saddr=' + curLatitude + ',' + curLongitude;
      var daddr = '&daddr=' + posLatitude + ',' + posLongitude;
      var distance = saddr + daddr;

      geolocationAccepted = true;

      navigateUrl = navigateUrl.replace('saddr', distance); 

      $navigateLink.attr('href', navigateUrl); //adding coordinates to href 
    }
  };

  var error = function(err) {
    geolocationAccepted = false;

    if(err.code === 1){

    }
  };

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, {
    enableHighAccuracy:false
  });
}
```

But it's only place the whole array into the link

Comment: You have 1 link but 5 sets of points... are you wanting to have 5 links, each with one set of coordinates?

Comment: yes, there can be uncounted number of links, it depends on markers and corresponding infowindows, from 1 to eternity, each infowindow consist of 3 tabs with a link class="location" inside each of it, so this links should looks like http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=60.2550968,28.6610835&daddr=48.8577748,2.3539295

Comment: what do you get if you do `console.log($navigateLink);` in the top of the `moveToStore` function?

Comment: it give me a list of all links in all my popups, when i call it after var $navigateLink = $pos.find('.location'), if i ll call it before it will show me "undefind"

Comment: anyway i have a unique id for each popup, that corresponds to the last item in the array: ["random-street-name", 48.8690284, 2.3215802, "store-1"<popup id],

Comment: That's your problem; you get an array of links, and you're therefore updating every link at the same time.  You need a more specific jQuery selector to get only one link at a time.  Can you update your question with some HTML for how these links are setup in their containers?

Comment: added some markup for you